# I can't get the new XNA project template to appear

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xna, installation, wizard

I'm trying to make a new XNA project from the template. I've installed xna and have both Visual Studio Professional 2010 and Visual C# Express 2010. I click "New Project" and look for anything related to XNA or Game Window or anything on the left had side but there is nothing there. I've reinstalled XNA but it's not there yet. How do I get those wizards to appear?

Comment: You need to install Visual Studio first.

Comment: I already installed both, Visual Studio first, then express edition

Comment: Why would you install Express if you already have professional? Also, did you have visual studio installed before you ran the XNA installer (be sure you didn't install the XNA redistributables, but you installed the SDK: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23714), because you need to.